# UiTextField in ViewController2 Change value of Struct Var

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, struct

I have two view Controllers connected with a tabBar. In the first tab, I see all buttons to add Repairs and Delete Repairs. In The First Step of my private project, I have Static values for the Repair times. Now in my second step, I wanted to change the time that a person needs to repair by the second tap, but when I go back after editing the time in the second VieController, the value of the struct didn't change.

```
ViewController.swift 

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var AddBrepair: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var AddOrepair: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var AddDrepair: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var GeniusNumber: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var AddBCrepair: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var CheckOutOrepair: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var CheckOutBrepair: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var CheckOutBCrepair: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var CheckOutDrepair: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var DisplayLeftNumber: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var RFPTime: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var CurrentTimerepair: UILabel!
let repairTime=RepairTime()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //RFPTime.text = repairTime.ReadyForPickup()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    //print(repairTime.getNumberOfRepairGenius())

}




@IBAction func Controller(sender: AnyObject) {

    repairTime.NumberOfRepairGenius(GeniusNumber.selectedSegmentIndex+1)
    CurrentTimerepair.text = String(format:"%.1f", repairTime.TimeOfRepair())
    RFPTime.text = String(repairTime.ReadyForPickup())
}

@IBAction func AddBr(sender: AnyObject) {

    repairTime.NumberOfBatteryRepair(repairTime.getNumberOfBatteryRepair()+1)
    CurrentTimerepair.text = String(format:"%.1f", repairTime.TimeOfRepair())
    RFPTime.text = String(repairTime.ReadyForPickup())

}

@IBAction func AddOr(sender: AnyObject) {

    repairTime.NumberOfOtherRepair(repairTime.getNumberOfOtherRepair()+1)
    CurrentTimerepair.text = String(format:"%.1f", repairTime.TimeOfRepair())
    RFPTime.text = String(repairTime.ReadyForPickup())

}

@IBAction func AddBCr(sender: AnyObject) {

repairTime.NumberOfBackCoverRepair(repairTime.getNumberOfBackCoverRepair()+1)
    CurrentTimerepair.text = String(format:"%.1f", repairTime.TimeOfRepair())
    RFPTime.text = String(repairTime.ReadyForPickup())

}

@IBAction func AddDr(sender: AnyObject) {

    repairTime.NumberOfDisplayRepair(repairTime.getNumberOfDisplayRepair()+1)
    CurrentTimerepair.text = String(format:"%.1f", repairTime.TimeOfRepair())
    RFPTime.text = String(repairTime.ReadyForPickup())

    //print("view controler")
    //print(

}

@IBAction func DeleteBr(sender: AnyObject) {
    if(repairTime.getNumberOfBatteryRepair() != 0){
    repairTime.NumberOfBatteryRepair(repairTime.getNumberOfBatteryRepair()-1)
    CurrentTimerepair.text = String(format:"%.1f", repairTime.TimeOfRepair())
        RFPTime.text = String(repairTime.ReadyForPickup())
    }

}
@IBAction func DeleteOr(sender: AnyObject) {
    if(repairTime.getNumberOfOtherRepair() != 0){
    repairTime.NumberOfOtherRepair(repairTime.getNumberOfOtherRepair()-1)
    CurrentTimerepair.text = String(format:"%.1f", repairTime.TimeOfRepair())
        RFPTime.text = String(repairTime.ReadyForPickup())
    }
}

@IBAction func DeleteBCr(sender: AnyObject) {
    if(repairTime.getNumberOfBackCoverRepair() != 0){

repairTime.NumberOfBackCoverRepair(repairTime.getNumberOfBackCoverRepair()-1)
    CurrentTimerepair.text = String(format:"%.1f", repairTime.TimeOfRepair())
        RFPTime.text = String(repairTime.ReadyForPickup())
    }
}
@IBAction func DeleteDr(sender: AnyObject) {
    if(repairTime.getNumberOfDisplayRepair() != 0){
    repairTime.NumberOfDisplayRepair(repairTime.getNumberOfDisplayRepair()-1)
    CurrentTimerepair.text = String(format:"%.1f", repairTime.TimeOfRepair())
        RFPTime.text = String(repairTime.ReadyForPickup())
    }
}

@IBAction func ShowQueuePop(sender: AnyObject) {
    let out="Display Repair: \(repairTime.getNumberOfDisplayRepair()) \n Other Repair: \(repairTime.getNumberOfOtherRepair()) \n Battery Repair: \(repairTime.getNumberOfBatteryRepair()) \n Back Cover Repair: \(repairTime.getNumberOfBackCoverRepair())"

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Current repair Queue", message: out
        , preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}



class RepairTime {

var optiontime = OptionTime()
var RepairGenius: Int = 1
var DisplayRepair: Int = 0
var OtherRepair: Int = 0
var BackCoverRepair: Int = 0
var BatteryRepair: Int = 0

func TimeOfRepair()->Double{
        var repairtimezwei: Double
        repairtimezwei=0.0
        var repairzeit: Int
        repairzeit=0
        repairzeit=(BatteryRepair*optiontime.BatteryTime)+(BackCoverRepair*optiontime.BCTime)+(DisplayRepair*optiontime.DisplayTime)+(OtherRepair*optiontime.OtherTime)
        //print(DisplayRepair)
        repairtimezwei = (Double(repairzeit)/Double(RepairGenius))+15.0



        return repairtimezwei
    }
```

so and this is my second viewController:

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

var optiontime = OptionTime()



@IBOutlet weak var DisplayTime: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var BatteryTime: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var BackCoverTime: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var OtherTime: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //RFPTime.text = repairTime.ReadyForPickup()

    // set TextField with Values of struct optionTime from class RepairTime
   DisplayTime.text=String(optiontime.DisplayTime)
    BatteryTime.text=String(optiontime.BatteryTime)
    BackCoverTime.text=String(optiontime.BCTime)
    OtherTime.text=String(optiontime.OtherTime)


    //set KeybardType for Textinputs 
    self.DisplayTime.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumbersAndPunctuation
    self.BatteryTime.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumbersAndPunctuation
    self.BackCoverTime.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumbersAndPunctuation
    self.OtherTime.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumbersAndPunctuation

    self.DisplayTime.delegate = self
   self.BatteryTime.delegate = self
   self.BackCoverTime.delegate = self
    self.OtherTime.delegate = self

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return false
}


@IBAction func TimeChangeDisplay(sender: AnyObject) {

    optiontime.DisplayTime = Int(DisplayTime.text!)!
print("vie controler 2")
    print(optiontime.DisplayTime)


}


@IBAction func TimeChangeBattery(sender: AnyObject) {
   optiontime.BatteryTime = Int(BatteryTime.text!)!
}


@IBAction func TimeChangeBC(sender: AnyObject) {
        optiontime.BCTime = Int(BackCoverTime.text!)!
}


@IBAction func TimeChangeOther(sender: AnyObject) {
    optiontime.OtherTime = Int(OtherTime.text!)!
}


}
```

My Problem is that the value of the struct after finishing the edit in the textfield didn't change.

Comment: Please fix your code formatting by indenting properly; very hard to read code that is broken up

Comment: Please supply the implementation of OptionTime. Also include debugging println()s at every step and include the raw textfield text as well as the computed Int value. Also explain what events your @IBActions are wired to...editingDidEnd, for example? Even if that's all correct, are you in fact triggering editingDidEnd by changing focus to another text field?

Comment: thx @SteveFerg for edit :)

Comment: @BaseZen my plan is that after finishing editing in Textfield you can go back to the first tap an so the new Calculated RepairTime but the method only calculate with the value that i have set in the Struct.

Comment: ok after one sleepless night i found the solution i used sharedInstance to work with both ViewController

Comment: It seems to be about half of all UI-related questions in any language boil down to "I don't understand the 'M' part of 'MVC' in any over-arching sense." In other words it's very hard to share the actual application data among the many GUI pieces. The ubiquitous framework pattern of carving up everything into dozens of little objects makes walls too high for novices to scale without help.